How to use custom headers for passing session_id and csrf_token in Django with database-backed sessions?
I'm using Django with a database-backed session storage, and as a result, the session_id is stored in cookies.
However, we're using a Caddy server that removes cookies from the request headers.
I need to:

Pass the session_id and csrf_token via custom headers (instead of cookies).
Use these custom headers for session validation and CSRF protection in Django.

Additionally, I am storing values in the session that are used to validate the request and fetch data from the session during API calls.
Is it possible to configure Django to accept and validate these custom headers (session_id and csrf_token) rather than reading them from cookies? If so, how can this be achieved?
Any advice or code examples would be much appreciated.


Attempting to include a custom header to retrieve the session ID.
